# Any ideas for a 'Today' icon?

Tags: gui-design, icons, calendar

I'm working on an app at the moment. I'm trying to replace the text with icons to allow easier transition to international markets.

One icon I'm struggling with is a 'today'. I've thought about a clock or a calendar but I think they don't quick fit.

Here is a mock up with just text for the icons.

[image: Mock up]

Comment: What is the case for preferring an icon? The common pattern for calendar applications (Google, Outlook, etc) is to write out the word "today" as you have done. Unless there's some clear need, you probably should not deviate from this pattern.

Comment: Sorry but icon requests are off topic for this site, as discussed in or [FAQ] and the [about] page.

Answer (score 3):

I think "Go to today" icon (this is the action in performs, isn't it?) should include three clear informations:

- that it refers to date (calendar icon is good for this)
- that it regards a day (making one day stick out should be good for it; you won't indicate that it is today's date, but I don't find it a problem, as today's date is a special one, so it should be quite clear that it refers to it)
- that it triggers going to that date

I don't know if it is a standard, but a calendar icon, with one day marked and an arrow pointing at it, should do the trick. Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Today* is one of those words that cannot easily be represented visually. An icon shouldn't have the user second-guessing what it does, so my suggestion is to use the date itself as the button, space permitting. So "Fri Mar 8th" or something along those lines, as a button so the user knows it's not just part of the interface.

Comment: I agree that sobox studio should stick with text, but I think there should always be an option for the user to get to "today" without having to recognize that "today" == "Fri Mar 8th". Not only is it helpful for users who can't remember what day it is (eg, myself), but there's a strong convention in calendar apps around this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a home icon for this purpose.

[image: Home Icon]

[Source](https://github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons/blob/master/WindowsPhone/light/appbar.home.png)

Comment: "Home" is semantically distinct from "today". I understand the question was specifically looking for an icon, but I think using the home icon is strictly inferior to writing out the word "today".

Comment: Agreed, but it was the closest icon that came to mind.

Comment: Are we supposed to answer the question or determine what should have been asked and answer that?

Comment: I don't know and hence refrained from answering but it seems like operating principle should be to provide appropriate guidance to the asker, which may entail revisiting the scope of his or her question. See this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35932/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-user-read-terms-and-conditions-before-continuing-a

Comment: Of course, if the question gets closed as off-topic, it's moot ;)