# Accepting multiple Terms and Conditions at once

Tags: usability, legal, terms-of-service

I am working on a mobile and web form. There are a few products X, Y, Z under an umbrella product, let's call it XYZ.

Is there a way for accepting multiple Terms and Conditions by placing all of them in one place? I can only think of the following layout. Or is it better to get customers to accept the terms and conditions one by one?

[image: prototype of combined terms and conditions]

Answer (score 6):

I'd ask this question a company lawyer. I saw some applications (for example, Eclipse) ask user to accept all licenses separately. Probably, this is due to country law prohibits signing multiple documents with a single signature.

Multiple agreements are placed into different pages or tabs of a form.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is an interesting pain point. I believe there’s separate terms and condition for separate applications in a parent app. So here’s few suggestion:

Suggestion 1: at the very beginning, let the user select which application he wants to move with, if ex. user want to move with appX then open only that terms page. There instead of next you can have the accept and close option.